# CoreAudio: Ausampler Unit polyphony

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit, coremidi

I'm currently trying to use the Ausampler Unit efficiently. I used the code from apple's sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011214-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

The downside seems to be that it instantly stops a note/sampe if the same note comes in again.
So if I send e.g. midi note 60 with the trombone preset loaded. And then while holding this I send note 60 again. It cuts off the first note event. Does anyone know if/how it is possible to hold every single note till a note off event (of this specific note) comes in?

Other question:
How can I change the volume of a note after it has been send? E.g. I sent midi note 60 and 70 with 100 velocity. While note 60 still plays I want to reduce the volue but keep note 70 up. This would be called midi aftertouch.

Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The AUSampler (`kAudioUnitSubType_Sampler`) is monotimbral ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570002/840992)) so in order to play two notes of the same pitch simultaneously, you will need two "instruments" - i.e. to instances of the AUSampler. In my projects, I have found that this doesn't add much to the memory overhead since the sound resources get shared.

As for aftertouch - I haven't explored that but it seems like the property you want is `kAUGroupParameterID_KeyPressure_FirstKey` (References [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitParametersReference/Reference/reference.html), and maybe [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2003/Jul/msg00393.html)).

```
Supporting the kAUGroupParameterID_KeyPressure parameter indicates to 
hosts that your audio unit supports polyphonic "aftertouch" key pressure.

Each of the 128 MIDI key numbers can have its own value for polyphonic 
aftertouch. To respond to aftertouch for a particular key, your audio 
unit needs to support an additional parameter specifically for that key. 
The aftertouch parameter ID for a given MIDI key is equal to the MIDI
key number plus 256. For example, the aftertouch parameter ID for MIDI 
key #60 (middle C) is:

60 + kAUGroupParameterID_KeyPressure_FirstKey = 316
```

If you get aftertouch working, post back some sample code.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this information! I did what you said and put 3 samplers in place for testing. If I play a lot of notes now my audio crackles. I put the 3 samplers in a mixer unit and from there to the output port. Did you do anything special to prevent this?

Comment: @Max - I have mostly used .sf2 (sound fonts) and not the approach of custom audio a la that LoadPresetDemo. Haven't had crackling with the .sf2 and my set up was the same: samplers > mixer > remoteIO. Maybe there are some special requirements for the custom audio and how they are defined in the preset - did you switch out the Apple supplied samples for your own? Check out AULab - and maybe post on the Apple Dev forum - not so much info here @ AUSampler/midi stuff.

Comment: @Max - Just came across this. Not @ crackles but interesting - http://www.electricpeelsoftware.com/2013/02/22/creating-aupreset-files.html

Comment: @TOMATO Thanks for your suggestion to deal with aftertouch.

Comment: I'll tag this as the right answer now, I don't believe it's possible with the AUSamplerUnit, so I stopped using it and I use FMOD now which works like a charm. Thanks foe the answer and comments!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is WRONG. **Timbre** and **Polyphony** are two **different** things. Mono timbral means that the midi device (in this case the AUSampler instance) can only play a single INSTRUMENT/PATCH at the same time, that has nothing to do with the amount of concurrent **notes** it can play for that single instrument.
A multi timbral device on the other hand, can play several instruments/patches (midi channels) at the same time.
The polyphony seems to be limited and hardcoded to 2 notes in the iOS version of the AUSampler and there seems to be no public api to change that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you get the voices numbers 2 `hardcoded to 2 notes` on iOS device? Any API to get this value? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**I don't think that AUSampler is limited to two note polyphony.** I am just doing research for my project and it is very important for me.

Have a look at this [piano keyboard plugin](http://www.binpress.com/app/piano-keyboard-for-ios/1282), author of it mentioned that it was made with **AUSampler** and from video you can see that it **plays four note chords easily**.

Comment: I can confirm with an app I wrote that the AUSampler can definitely play more than 2 notes at the same time. So far I have not found any info on if there is an actual limit, or if the sampler just tries to play as many notes as possible (ie. 128 voices, at max 128 MIDI notes). Of course this should depend on the device in use.